# Visual Studio 2017 do not display grunt tasks in task runner explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, gruntjs

Visual Studio 2017 can open any folder instead of a .NET project.

So I opened a folder in a .NET Web Project using `file`->`open`->`open folder`. And the root level of that folder has `Gruntfile.js`, `package.json` and `node_modules` has all required node modules. However, task runner explorer does not show grunt tasks at all.

If I open the website project, e.g. `file`->`open project/solution` then grunt tasks will show up in the task runner explorer.